# Testing keyboard issue , is it hardware related?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, hardware, keyboard-layout

I use ubuntu 14.04.

My laptop's keyboard didn't get any damage but suddenly the keyboard gave me some problem.

When I try to push `7` key it recognize as `9`

`Left Shift`  is not working.

Also `super key` is not working.

Also I tried in boot menu `7` key also recognized as `9` , So is it really hardware problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any good idea for this situation but, When I tried to use external keyboard , my laptop's keyboard worked as expected. So I think , can some usb cables or adapters or usb fans make short circuit or something like that?